# How to parse and solve equation string in Java?

Tags: java, string, equation-solving

I have a string like 3x^2+5X+7 and what I want to do is, get x value from the user and make the program solve this equation. I couldn't figure it out how I am gonna do this so far. I would be really glad if you help me.

Comment: take a look at this https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

Comment: Create a stack of characters,
 Put all Chars to that stack 
now you need to get the priority of each traversing on the stack

Comment: Add code snippet to here for discussing your approach and let us see what is wrong on your code then you can request help for non-working states or lines.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
int x = 42;
String foo = "3*x^2+5*x+7";
String input = foo.replaceAll("x", x);
System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
```

([How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form))